# Cannot connect to email server from a remote pc

Tags: email-server, remote-access, port, telnet

When I try to connect to my mailserver from my home pc like this

```
telnet whomakescoffee.com 25
```

I cannot connect. If I type in the same command on my server there is no problem. I have also tried turning off windows firewall. If I use the command (on the server):

```
iptables -L
```

I have the following rules

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I am using slicehost where I set up a VPS. Can they block me on port 25 or what is going on?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: It seems far more likely that your home ISP is blocking port 25.  That is somewhat common these days as a way to reduce spam.  Can you connect to anything else on port 25?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed. It is probably your ISP. Change your mail server to listen on a second port, such as 26 or 587 and try that.